# A portrait of Bombelli

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

Is there any known portrait of [Rafael Bombelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Bombelli)? I don't think so, but if you visit his [MacTutor biography](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Bombelli.html), you will see there this picture:

[image]

It is clear to me that this cannot possibly be a picture of a XVI<sup>th</sup> century Italian. So:

1. Does anyone here know who is this person?
2. Is there any known portrait of Bombelli?

Comment: Could you provide a reason for your "it is clear" statement?

Comment: The clothing and the hair are not consistent with what I know about upper-class Italians from the sixteenth century.

Comment: Funny, google returns many "portraits of Bombelli", none of them with a source. One place slaps Bombelli's name on  Vieta's portrait. It is not looking good.

Comment: The charicature you have included certainly reminds me of Cauchy.  The clothing (collars and lapels) and the "comb-over" hair look just like the popular image of Cauchy we see on, for example, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy).  Not sure if Cauchy ever sported facial hair.

Comment: I do not find nothing "strange" that we have no portrait of Bombelli...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Me neither. We also have no portraits of Scipione del Ferro or of Ludovico Ferrari.

Comment: I've browsed the 20th Century Italian editions/studies of Bombelli's Algebra : no portrait at all. Thus, if the manuscript sources has no pictures, it is hard to imagine that we can find it after so many centuries.